# Robustly identify which shell is running

Tags: python, shell, popen

I have a Python program which needs to execute a different process (I use `subprocess.Popen` for that). I need this execution to behave as if the following was typed by the user on the shell command prompt:

```
$ source path/to/some_file
$ ./some_program
```

I expect I will use `shell=True` and some form of command chaining to first run `source` and then execute the program. However, I am facing the following problem:

The shell which launches my Python program could be `bash`, `sh`, `tcsh` (or maybe some other flavour of `csh`). I need to source a different `some_file` based on which shell is running. Is there a way to determine this? Either in Python or by running something inside `Popen(..., shell=True)`, both would do.

I was considering writing some sort of "shell polyglot" to get different output from different shells, but my shell skills (especially in csh) aren't up to such a task. What options do I have?

Comment: You can force a particular shell by using the [executable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) argument with `shell=True`.

Comment: On Unix, the used shell defaults to /bin/sh regardless of which shell the user is actually using.

Comment: @Cairnarvon, yea, but /bin/sh is symlinked to different things on different linuxes.

Comment: The usage of ``shell=True`` is discouraged..

Comment: i don't know if this helps :)   `s=$($? 2>&1|grep -o "^[^:]*")` then you check `$s`

Comment: @PavelAnossov, /bin/sh is part of POSIX; if alternatives don't provide a superset of its features, they're *broken*. I'm not aware of any Unix-like that does that.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Solaris `/bin/sh` doesn't provide a superset of the POSIX shell but isn't "broken" as far as POSIX compliance is concerned. `/bin/sh` is actually not specified by POSIX. Each compliant OS is free to decide what PATH is to be used for the POSIX compliant shell (`/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` on Solaris 10 and older). It is a Python convention to launch `/bin/sh` by default when Popen is called on Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..what about spawning the shell and then communicating with it?

I mean, something like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
proc.communicate("source path/to/some_file\n"
                 "./some_program\n")
```

Since you want to execute a two commands inside a specific shell, I think this would be the best solution you have.

Otherwise, you might find that your shell accepts arguments such as an "init script" and "initial command"; in this case, and if you only need to use that specific shell, you should use them; for example, bash accepts `--init-file file` and `-c command` that would do the job (`--init-file` will be loaded instead of bashrc).

Answer (score 3):

Which shell is used by `subprocess.Popen()` is not determined by the parent shell used to launch Python.  Rather, the shell used by Python is always `/bin/sh` by default, and you can change it if you need by explicitly specifying an executable in `Popen()`.

But really, any given shell script can be written for one specific type of shell.  Let's say it's `bash`.  Then you can simply ignore these details on the Python side by writing a shell script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source path/to/some_file
exec ./some_program
```

There you go: a complete launcher script which switches to bash at the start, sources the necessary bits, and launches your program.  Any reasonable shell should be able to run it, so now you needn't worry about exactly which shell Python invokes...plus you have a more repeatable way to launch your program outside of Python.